# Django - How to access a python global variable in multiple pages?

Tags: python, django

In one of my Django application, I use a python global variable in a Django page (page One), as follows:

```
global abc
abc = test
```

Now what I want is, I want to access that variable from another page (page Two).
How can I access that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global variable accessible by all apps, you can put it in `settings.py`. Then you can access it from other views:

```py
from django.conf.settings import abc
```

Comment: This is not a variable of constant value. It will change on every page.